# Scala: higher order function to concatenate Strings

Tags: scala

I'm starting with Scala and now I am talking about higher order functions but I am having a hard time dealing with this way of programming using functions as inputs.

I must code a higher order function **using only fold, scan and/or reduce** that concatenates a string like so:

```
concatenate(List("S", "T", "R", " example!") , f)
//> res1: List[String] = List(STR example!, TR example!, R example!, " example!", "")
```

Does anyone know how can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `scan` only:

```
List("S", "T", "R", " example!").reverse.scan("")((x, y) => y + x).reverse
// res72: List[String] = List(STR example!, TR example!, R example!, " example!", "")
```

Use `scanRight`:

```
List("S", "T", "R", " example!").scanRight("")(_+_)
// res73: List[String] = List(STR example!, TR example!, R example!, " example!", "")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you just explain to me what does this do: "(x, y) => y + x" ?

Comment: It's used to guarantee the paste order of left + right, notice the list is reversed initially, if using `x + y`, then you will end up with `example! RTS` instead of the order you wanted.